# Adding html tag thru jquery

Tags: jquery, insert

i have the following html

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3 collapsable">
<div class="someclass"></div>
<a href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/" title="View all posts filed under Parent Category I">
    Parent Category I
</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6">
        <a class="" href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/child-category-i/" title="View all posts filed under Child Category I">
            Child Category I
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="parent cat-item cat-item-7 collapsable lastCollapsable">
        <div class="someclass"></div>
        <a href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/child-category-ii/" title="View all posts filed under Child Category II">
            Child Category II
        </a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-9 last">
                <a href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/child-category-ii/grandchild-category-i/" title="View all posts filed under Grandchild Category I">
                    Grandchild Category I
                </a> 
            </li>
```

using the above html and jquery, how it is possible to add a

```
<span class="folder">
```

after every li.parent class and  after every parents anchor tag.
so finally above html will look like

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3 collapsable">
<div class="someclass"></div>
<a href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/" title="View all posts filed under Parent Category I">
    Parent Category I
</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6">
        <a class="" href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/child-category-i/" title="View all posts filed under Child Category I">
            Child Category I
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="parent cat-item cat-item-7 collapsable lastCollapsable">
        <span class="folder"> // <-------------------- Want this
            <div class="someclass"></div>
            <a href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/child-category-ii/" title="View all posts filed under Child Category II">
                Child Category II
            </a>
        </span> // <------------------------ Closing span of what I Want
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-9 last">
                <a href="http://demo.mysite.com/category/parent-category-i/child-category-ii/grandchild-category-i/" title="View all posts filed under Grandchild Category I">
                    Grandchild Category I
                </a> 
            </li>
```

this means to append a span class to each parent class of a li and closing span in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap the children of the element:

```
$(".parent").children().wrapAll("<span class='folder' />");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hnwkb/) (inspect the output in Firebug/Developer tools to see the new `span`).

**Update** having looked back over code, I realised that you actually only want to wrap *some* of the children of `.parent` in the new `span`. If that is your final HTML structure, then you can do it by supplying a selector to `children`:

```
$(".parent").children("div, a").wrapAll("<span class='folder' />");
```

Here's [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/hnwkb/2/).

Comment: thank you for your support, but still could not get the desired result.my final code and result are shown in demo link mentioned below. would appreciate if you could dig a little more

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. The wrapper function won't work because you're trying to wrap multiple elements at once.

```
var x  = $('.parent.cat-item-7').contents();
$('.parent.cat-item-7').empty();
$('.parent.cat-item-7').append('<span class="folder"></span>');

$('.parent.cat-item7 .folder').append(x);
```

Comment: This will wrap each child, instead of all the children, and it will duplicate the text: http://jsfiddle.net/hnwkb/1/

Comment: @JamesAllardice Yeah I noticed that that's why I changed it :) but still thanks for the warning

Comment: somwhow i get unexpected result which i am not able to explain properly , can you please check here [link]http://demo.mysimplewp.com/demo-collapsible-categories/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for this:

```
$("<span class='folder' />").appendTo('.parent');
```

This will makes it happen.

Comment: This will just insert an empty `span` after all the children of `.parent`. The OP wants to wrap the children of `.parent`.